# Microsoft AJAX Force sync

Tags: javascript, ajax

using the microsoft ajax framework, I make several ajax calls. I would like for them to actually be synchronous though, but I cannot figure out how to do this.

As a side note, I can't seem to find any good doc on microsoft ajax framework library functions. What is a good resource?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a good starting reference for the APIs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341002.aspx